# Excel: Correct way to create dynamic data validation drop downs

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I would like to populate data validation dropdowns each time I launch a sheet. The data in the dropdowns may change from time to time as the dropdown contents is derived from a list of items I pull from a COM dll used in my addin. I create the dropdowns like this:

```
void AddFieldValidationToCells<T>(Excel.Range range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            return;

        List<string> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Select(v => v.ToString())
            .ToList();
        list.Sort();

        foreach (Excel.Range cell in range)
        {
            cell.Validation.Delete();
            cell.Validation.Add(
                Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
                Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
                Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                string.Join(",", list),
                Type.Missing);

            cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly. The only issue is that if the sheet were to crash, when I reopen it, I get the following error which I believe relates to the fact that the data in the validation list no longer has a reference:

[image]

If the sheet is shut down properly, my code removed the validations and this error does not occur, but if the sheet for some reason hangs or otherwise crashes, is it necessary for me to write this data to the sheet to make it persistent to avoid this message?